# How do I get all records from custom table via wordpress rest api?

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I have a custom table created in wordpress database called `custom_users`. I want to get all records inside custom_users table through the API that I created.

**functions.php**

```
function get_wp_custom_users() {
  global $wpdb;
    $row = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT * FROM wp_custom_users");
    return $row;
}

add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
    register_rest_route( 'wpcustomusers/v1', '/all/', array(
    methods' => 'GET',
    'callback' => 'get_wp_custom_users'
    ) );
} );
```

The endpoint can be accessed like this: http://localhost/mywebsite/wp-json/wpcustomusers/v1/all

When I access the endpoint via `POSTMAN`, I am only seeing `one record`.

Do you know how can I improve my get_wp_custom_users() method to retrieve all records? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using [get_row](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/get_row/), which (as the name implies) fetches one row.

To get multiple rows, I'd use [query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/query/) instead.

```
function get_wp_custom_users() {
  global $wpdb;
  $row = $wpdb->query("SELECT * FROM wp_custom_users");
  return $row;
}
```